# Consistent build process for Bootstrap project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, less

For an ASP.Net Web Application, we have after some consideration decided to refresh the UI. We are migrating from an ancient version of jQuery.UI to Bootstrap (v.3). Appearance wise we are happy and it was easy enough to make this happen.

We use Less and Sass to make it easier to use variables for colours and such properties. This also works fine.

But now to my concern. The build process to customize Bootstrap involves such a long list of components. So we have (This is in Visual Studio 2017):
Npm
NodeJS
Grunt
Bower
NPM Task Runner (to run grunt in VS)
452 (!!) modules in the node_modules directory

How on earth do you do to keep this consistent, ie. since npm update will potentially download new versions node, grunt, any of the modules etc. Of course one wants a build on any build environment to result in identical result, which has usually never been a problem before this change but now it feels like a huge risk. Our build server Jenkins doesn't really play either, so we still need to have the output css/js in the version system to allow the build server to build the solution.

Would you: 
1. Split bootstrap into a separate Visual Studio solution (or configuration) and always commit the resulting css/js and see that output as the "master"? This feels tempting at the moment. In that case, Jenkins wouldn't need to know how to build this or download modules etc. But it goes against the principle of versioning only the input to a build process.

2. Other solutions (not involving hard-coding the version number in all the 452 package.json files)

Thanks for any input.

Comment: What version of Node are you using.

Comment: We use version 5.4.1 for node

Comment: Next, what do you mean by "Our build server Jenkins doesn't really play either"? Are you not able to configure Jenkins to properly build your project?

Comment: Yes Jenkins is able to build the C#/Asp.net parts of the project, but since it doesnt have the NPM Task Runner or Node, I haven't found how to run the grunt tasks and how to be  sure the same versions of all of the 500 different components that are needed to build a specific version of our software.

Comment: Are you not able to install Node on the build server?

Comment: Ok so let us just assume I can get everything to run in Jenkins. Is there a way people use to keep all these modules intact version wise. If I build a specific version of the product in 5 years I would still expect the output css/js to be the same, even if a lot of new versions of all these modules have been released.

Comment: Yes. That's the purpose of `package.json`/`package-lock.json`. The specific version you're building should have a package.json associated with it, and when ran/installed will use those specific modules and versions.